# How to prevent onTouch for parent Linear Layout from executing multiple times child?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-event

On touch event for a lienar layout multiple screens pops up. It seems that the ontouch event gets fired twice for each child element of the linear layout. How can I prevent this from firing twice. 
On click event for the same linear layout causes, the linear layout onclick event to be fired on second click and not on the first click. I am not understanding where I am going wrong. Please help.

-- XML

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_button_sub"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_home_item"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:inputType="none" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:duplicateParentState="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_subs" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:duplicateParentState="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:text="Subscriptions"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Normal.Text.Size" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_button_find"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Home.Item.Spacing.Vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_home_item"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:inputType="none">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:duplicateParentState="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_find" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:duplicateParentState="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:text="Find Nearby"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/Normal.Text.Size" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

-- Activity on Oncreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    linearLayoutSubs = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_button_sub);
    linearLayoutFind = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_button_find);

    linearLayoutSubs.setOnTouchListener(new mOnTouchListener());
    linearLayoutFind.setOnTouchListener(new mOnTouchListener());
}
```

-- onTouch listener

```
public class  mOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    Intent intent = null;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.layout_button_subscriptions:
                intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, Subs.class);//class for navigation
                break;
            case R.id.layout_button_find_nearby:
                intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, Find.class);//class for navigation
                break;
        }

        if(intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting android:splitMotionEvents

Comment: do u refer onClick event or OnTouch event?

Comment: use a flag if it helps, where you can check if the touch event has been fired or not. and accordingly write the code for showing the popup.

Comment: Thanks Sainath but this is not working. I am still getting the events fired twice for every touch.

Comment: @Dinesh I have tried with both... With onTouchEvent the event is getting fired twice and with onclick to make the event fired I need to click the linear Layout twice.It is not working for single click and If I ll place a flag that may not let the event fire when user is intentionally trying to fire that event twice one after another

Comment: @user2703132 thats contradictory.. you want the event to be fired twice, and you donot want it to be fired twice. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` from `layout_button_sub` and `layout_button_find` in your layout xml.
This prevents the first touch/click event from being consumed by a focus change.

Then, change your `OnTouchListener` to an `OnClickListener`:

```
private class mOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    Intent intent;

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       switch (v.getId()) 
       {
           case R.id.layout_button_sub: 
                intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, Subs.class);
                break;
           case R.id.layout_button_find: 
                intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, Find.class);
                break; 
        }

        if (intent != null) 
        {
            startActivity(intent); 
        } 
    }       
}
```

And set it as such for your LinearLayouts:

```
mOnClickListener listener = new mOnClickListener();
linearLayoutSubs.setOnClickListener(listener);
linearLayoutFind.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

The `onTouch()` event fires on several MotionEvents: `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, etc. Every time you "clicked" with an `OnTouchListener`, the method was firing, at minimum, once when you put your finger down and once when you lifted your finger. Since your original `onTouch()` method didn't account for the different actions, `startActivity()` was being called for every touch event.

Comment: Thanks a lot mike, I was getting the result earlier on double click. So, I was avoiding that. Can u explain me the reason if possible...

Comment: and can u tel me why onTouch was causing multiple screens... I think It was due to the child events which were causing the evnt to fire multiple times.... Is there any we can avoid it getiing fired multiple times... If the reason is correct...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is because you have not defined actions MOVE, UP and DOWN for the touch. Try writing your code in **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN**, If this works for you.

```
    case R.id.layout_button_subscriptions:{   
      switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                              {

                                 break;
                              }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                            startActivity(new Intent(AppActivity.this,Subs.class));
                        break;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Tried to add action evnt to it even then it is firing twice.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake from the code I can see is that you are setting on touch listener twice, instead of the do following

```
mOnTouchListener listener =  new mOnTouchListener();
linearLayoutSubs.setOnTouchListener(listener);
linearLayoutFind.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

if possible use the if else condition in the onTouch and whenever the onTouch has happend return true from that position only.

since many times it's not returning from that position and hence the event is fired twice.

Comment: Tried with the above solution but that didn't worked. Moreover, for because of the switch case true is returned only once .